# How to set project's classpath to Scene Builder?

Tags: java, jar, scenebuilder

Suppose I have some project, like Maven, Gradle or some IDE. And it has custom controls, which may use dependencies from the libraries.

How to pass this information to Scene Builder?

Note, that I can't add each JAR manually, since it is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Gluon SceneBuilder has support for maven repositories

Comment: So, how to activate this feature?